# what is the difference between a function and a callable object in python?

Tags: python

```
class Adder:
      def __call__(self, x, y):
          return x + y

add1 = Adder()
```

```
def add2(x, y):
    return x + y
```

What's the difference between `add1` and `add2` other than the type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your super-simple example. there's no practical difference, since functions are also callable objects.

However, a callable object is an **object** of a class that you write, so you may write this code:

```
class Counter:
    def __init__(self, value = 0):
        self.n = 0

    def __call__(self):
        self.n += 1
        return self.n

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.n)

redWins = Counter()
blueWins = Counter()

if foo():
    redWins()
else:
    blueWins()

print("Red has won {} times.\nBlue has won {} times."
      .format(redWins, blueWins))
```

And you'll find it hard to implement such a class using only functions. Even if you try to do it with global variables, you can't have separate instances of one single global variable.

See more: [Functions, Callable Objects, and how both are created in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40182637/5958455)

Comment: @khelwood Sorry I was learning C/C++ at the time.

Comment: This can trivially be implemented by a generator function along the lines of `def counter(): n = 0; while True: n += 1; yield n;`

Comment: `++n` is just `n`

Comment: This can be trivially implemented with closures too.

Comment: @mkrieger1 or `import itertools;  c = counter(); next(c)`

Comment: Oh and yes: functions are objects too you know ?

Comment: Oh and yes: to use a custom callable as a method you'll have to implement the descriptor protocol support (cf https://wiki.python.org/moin/FromFunctionToMethod)

Answer (score 3):

In your example, there's no functional difference but since `add1` is an object, you can store information in the members:

```
class Adder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__memory = 0
    def __call__(self, x, y):
        self.__memory += x
        return x+y+self.__memory

add1 = Adder()
print(add1(10,10))
print(add1(10,10))
```

you get `30` then `40`. You can do that with a function, but then you need a global variable, and using global variables is really asking for trouble.

Comment: You don't need globals to do this with a function - just use a closure and you're done.