# How to stack multiple calls?

Tags: python, higher-order-functions

I am in a python class, and one of the assignments is to create a function that can "chain" multiple calls. For example, I have a function, say. I could write say() and nothing would return. I could write say('hi')() and it would return 'hi'. I could write say('hi')('my')('name')('is')('joe') and it would return 'hi my name is joe'. I'm pretty sure we're supposed to use higher order functions, but I can't wrap my head around it and what I've tried so far certainly isn't right:

```
sayString = ""

say(x):
    compose sayHelp(x)

def sayHelp(x):
    global sayString
    return sayString + x

def compose(f, g):
    return lambda x: f(x)+g(x)
```

Not really sure what to do, I know it doesn't work because it's trying to call a str function rather than say, but how do I make it recognize otherwise?

Comment: If you want your function `say()` to simply print something, then you just print your argument and `return say`. Having it return a value that's also callable is more difficult and probably not what you're supposed to do. You might find this fun, though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935313/how-to-chain-multiple-arguments-in-python-add123-6/38935526#38935526

Comment: Thanks! That actually did the trick with a little bit of modification. I appreciate it.

Comment: Just want to mention the toolz library for creating curried functions without fuss: https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/curry.html